# Whats a better way to call a form from another form

Tags: vb6

Say I have 2 forms named, Form1 and Form2. I want to call a function abc() in Form2 from Form1. Which one is better and why?

Method 1:

```
 'In Form1
  Form2.abc()
```

Method 2:

```
 'In Form1
  Dim oFrm As New Form2
  oFrm.abc()
```

Comment: Your method 1 would only work for if the function is Shared, the second method is for instance functions.

Comment: @SLaks So r u saying there is not much difference between these 2 methods??

Comment: @SLaks Ok. So then which one is better?

Comment: There is nothing "evil" about the default instance of each Form you define.  Somebody needs a nap.

Comment: Ok. So this still has not answered my question. Instead, it has started a debate.

Comment: Method 2 is much better because it allows you to have several instances of `Form2` visible at the same time. Method 1 is a legacy feature for compatibility with MS Access way of handling forms where you can reference controls from application forms in queries e.g. `WHERE Name = Form2!txtName` -- pure evil violation of app tiers separation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In VB6 when a program runs, as soon as you reference a form via it's form name VB6 creates an instance of that form. That instance is also added to the Forms collection.

You can discover which forms have been instantiated using this code or a suitable variation thereof:

```
Dim frmCurrent As Form
Dim output As String
For Each frmCurrent In Forms
    output = output & frmCurrent.Name & vbCrLf
Next
MsgBox output
```

So when you call Form2.abc() you are calling the abc procedure on the newly created instance of the Form2 form (you can substitute the word class for form if it helps your understanding).

When it comes time to exit the program you can get a type of error where the program is hanging around in memory but is not visible on the screen because you have closed all the visible forms but not the ones instantiated via calls like `Form2.abc`. This lead to the popular 'close all forms' code being added to the exit procedure of many VB6 programs:

```
Private Sub cmdExit_Click()
   Dim current As Form
   Dim output As String
   For Each current In Forms
      Unload current
   Next
End Sub
```

When you dimension a variable and assign a new instance of Form2 to it you are creating a new form with scope according to the variable. The instance is **not** added to the Forms collection:

```
Dim frmNew As New frmTest
frmNew.abc

Dim frmCurrent As Form
Dim output As String
For Each frmCurrent In Forms
    output = output & frmCurrent.Name & vbCrLf
Next
MsgBox output 'Does not include frmNew aka frmTest
```

Thus your second method is generally the better one as it doesn't create an instance of Form2 in the Forms collection or reuse an exisiting instance that may give you an unexpected result.

Answer (score 1):

If you will only ever have one instance of Form2 then just use Method 1.

If you need more than one instance or anticipate ever needing more than 1 instance then use Method 2.

Comment: Short, sweet, practical answer.

Comment: @ClaraOnager Agreed, your answer below is excellent in comparison.  You've got my upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are asking this question I assume you have form2 already loaded, so i would call the function directly (option 1)

It also depends on the nature of your function .. does it interfere with form2? does it use data from form2? .... if so i would call the function directly

If it's a global function i would not put it in form2, but in a module

If you want to load a new instance of form2, and have the user interact with that, then i would go with option 2

Answer (score 0):

The first method is good if you know that Form2 is already loaded, and FunctionName() can be called globally in any context. The second method is best if you only need to execute a specific function in Form2 which has not been loaded yet. However, you will need to pay attention to memory leakage:

---

Calling a function from `Form2` using `Form2.FunctionName()` will do the following:

1- Check If `Form2` is loaded? If not, it will be loaded first.
2- the `FunctionName()` is executed
3- `Form2` will remain in memory until it is specifically Unloaded.

You will have to clean up, by manually unloading Form2 by

```
Unload Form2
```

Otherwise, when you *think*  that you have closed `Form1` and you ended the program, `Form2` is already loaded and the process of your executable file is already there in the TaskManager.

---

Calling `FunctionName()` using

```
Dim oFrm as New Form2
oFrm.FunctionName()
```

will ensure to load an instance of Form2 (in the local context of your code) then execute the function, but you still need to unload it when you are done with it by :

```
Unload oFrm
```

Otherwise your program will leak memory as in the first case.

Answer (score 0):

change private `Sub Form_Load()` to public `Sub Form_Load()` , then can call it from second form

for example, from form2 you want to call form1 `form_load()`

should use: call `form1.form_load()`